# Boxen download archieves from S3-bucket

Tags: macos, homebrew, boxen

I am attempting to download a file from a private S3-bucket, through Boxen puppet scripts. However, I haven't found any examples how to do so. All I found was readme's discussing the environment variables (which I set).

But how can I download an archive from S3 and install it locally? Any good examples? Is this done through homebrew or a puppet script?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[puppet-minecraft](https://github.com/boxen/puppet-minecraft) does this with a publicly reachable AWS S3 bucket. Perhaps it can help you.

Check out the manifest `init.pp` [>here<](https://github.com/boxen/puppet-minecraft/blob/master/manifests/init.pp), where you'll find this snippet showing the URL that's grabbing the item from AWS S3.

```rb
package { 'Minecraft':
  source   => 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/Minecraft.dmg',
  provider => 'appdmg'
}
```

Mincraft isn't the only example. I found others in my repo by running on my Mac.:

```sh
mdfind -onlyin /opt/boxen/repo/shared s3 | grep manifest

/opt/boxen/repo/shared/vmware_fusion/manifests/init.pp
/opt/boxen/repo/shared/ruby/manifests/version.pp
/opt/boxen/repo/shared/minecraft/manifests/init.pp
/opt/boxen/repo/shared/java/manifests/init.pp
/opt/boxen/repo/shared/istatmenus4/manifests/init.pp
/opt/boxen/repo/shared/heroku/manifests/init.pp
/opt/boxen/repo/shared/github_for_mac/manifests/init.pp
```